Snowflake Procedure 'STATEMENT_ERROR'
I am trying to call the snowflake procedure to get CDC records for my data. I get the below issue
Error:'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 20 at position 12 : SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 87 (line 57)
invalid identifier 'ID' (line 57)
I have created streams on top of a table which has only inserts. I loop through each record in streams, find if there is an id in history_cdc table, update its meta column and insert a new record. If there is no id in cdc table, I insert a new record.
Not getting where exactly is the statement error
create or replace procedure public.proc_get_cdc()
returns varchar(16777216)
language sql
execute as owner
as 
$$
declare
    max_meta_created timestamp_ntz;
    c1 cursor for select * from public.streams_static;
    exists_flag integer default 0;
    id varchar;
begin
    create or replace table public.streams_static as select * from public.dummy_streams;

    select max(meta_created) into max_meta_created from public.leads_history_cdc;

    if (max_meta_created is null) then
        insert into public.history_cdc(data, meta_created, meta_updated, meta_start, meta_expiry, meta_active_row, meta_operation) 
        select parse_json(data), meta_created, meta_updated, current_date, '2049-12-31', true, METADATA$ACTION from public.streams_static;
    end if;
    else
    for record in c1 do
            id:= parse_json(record.data):Id::varchar;

            select count(*) into exists_flag from public.leads_history_cdc where parse_json(data):Id::varchar = id;

            if (exists_flag > 0) then
                update public.history_cdc 
                set 
                    meta_expiry = (select max(meta_created) from public.streams_static where parse_json(data):Id::varchar = id),
                    meta_operation = 'delete',
                    meta_active_row = false,
                    meta_updated = (select max(meta_created) from public.streams_static where parse_json(data):Id::varchar = id)
                where 
                    parse_json(data):Id::varchar = id 
                    and meta_created = (select max(meta_created) from public.leads_history_cdc where parse_json(data):Id::varchar = id);

                insert into public.history_cdc(data, meta_created, meta_updated, meta_active_row, meta_operation, meta_start, meta_expiry)
                select parse_json(data), current_date, current_date, true, 'insert', current_date, '2049-12-31' from public.streams_static where parse_json(data):Id::varchar = id;
            else
                insert into public.history_cdc(data, meta_created, meta_updated, meta_active_row, meta_operation, meta_start, meta_expiry)
                select parse_json(data), current_date, current_date, true, 'insert', current_date, '2049-12-31' from public.streams_static where parse_json(data):Id::varchar = id;
            end if;
    end for;

    drop table public.streams_static;

    return null;
end;
$$;


Does the JSON data you're parsing with parse_json(data) contain a salesforce id field? Seems the string SALESFORCE_ID is substituted into the query somehow unquoted, such that it looks to the compiler like a column name (or other object, e.g. table). To me, the first occurrence of parse_json(data) on line 19 looks a bit odd. Since record.data doesn't exist until the cursor c1 is defined below, what defines data at this point in the code? A few sample rows for public.streams_static and public.history_cdc, and an example json might clarify things a bit.

History_table contains column  called data which is of type variant. Inside, I have a column called Id. So I access it likeparse_json(record.data):Id::varchar.
I am using cursor based for loop in snowflake. So, data will have some value, by the time it is called.
Example of values inside data column - {"col1":"val1","col2":"val2",..........}

I'd start by commenting out all the DML statements in your proc (SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE etc) except the first one, run the proc, check it runs, enable the next statement, run the proc, repeat etc. until it errors - then you'll know exactly which statement is giving this error - and we can look in more detail at what that statement is doing

I am not sure,
but SQL based snowflake stored-procedure has issue with "insert into" command since, for stored procedure "into" keywords is used for identifier.
In the past I have asked for it in Snowflake but didn't get any valid justification.
Link of the issue.
Stored Procedure with Snowflake Scripting to Insert Data
